# SQLITE: stop execution if select returns specific value

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqltransaction

Is there any way to write an SQL input file for sqlite that would somehow "throw" an error, eg. exited the transaction with rollback, if a condition isn't met?

I have a script that is supposed to do something, but only if there is a certain row in one table. If it's not there, the execution of the script might have fatal results and corrupt the db.

The script is only started on demand right now, but I would prefer to add a fail-safe which would prevent its execution in case there is some issue.

Basically what I need is something like

```
/* IF */ SELECT value FROM meta WHERE key = 'version' /* != hardcoded_version_string THROW SOME EXCEPTION */
```

Is there any way to accomplish that? In Postgre / Oracle this could be done using PLSQL but I am not sure if sqlite support any such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

[Triggers](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) can use the RAISE function to generate errors:

```
CREATE VIEW test AS SELECT NULL AS value;
CREATE TRIGGER test_insert
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON test
BEGIN
  SELECT RAISE(FAIL, 'wrong value')
  WHERE NEW.value != 'fixed_value';
END;

INSERT INTO test SELECT 'fixed_value';
INSERT INTO test SELECT 'whatever';
Error: wrong value
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to write an SQL input file for sqlite that would
>   somehow "throw" an error, eg. exited the transaction with rollback, if
>   a condition isn't met?

One workaround may be to create dummy table and explicitly violate `NULL` constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE meta("key" VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO meta("key") VALUES ('version');

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE dummy(col INT NOT NULL);
```

Transaction:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO dummy(col)
SELECT NULL                    -- explicit insert of NULL
FROM meta  
WHERE "key" = 'version';
-- Error: NOT NULL constraint failed: dummy.col

-- rest code
INSERT INTO meta("key")
VALUES ('val1');

INSERT INTO meta("key")
VALUES ('val2');
-- ...

COMMIT;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/b0289/1/0)**</kbd>

Keep in mind that SQLite is not procedural language and this solution is a bit ugly.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like I've got some ugly 3-steps decision for all of us:

1. Create a dummy table:

   ```
   create table stop_script(dummy);
   ```
2. Create a trigger:

   ```
   create trigger before_stop_script_insert
   before insert on stop_script for each row
   begin
     select raise(FAIL,'Script execution is stopped!');
   end;
   ```
3. To break an execution anywhere you like in your script use the following:

   ```
   insert into stop_script
   select null
   where 1=1; --Your own case to break the script execution
   ```

P.S.
It's a pity that raise function accepts only const values, but it's much better than nothing.